# Unsupervised Machine Learning Algorithm for Autonomous Image Processing and Tracking

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

I am trying to prototype a Mathematica application that will enable Autonomous Intruder & Anomalous Event Detection, Tracking and Alarm to web users those who want to autonomously and asynchronously monitor their private spaces such as homes, offices as well as outdoor spaces such as backyards, roads and recreation facilities using inexpensive commercial Internet-connected IP-cams and webcams.

I want to employ a proven and tested unsupervised algorithm that will help me accomplish my goal.  Any idea which one would be the best? What are the Mathematica functions that will help me customize such an algorithm? I am using network license of Mathematica-8.

Comment: The question title sounds like a paper title.

Answer (score 7):

[Here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/11/10/how-to-make-a-webcam-intruder-alarm-with-mathematica/) is a starting point: Intrusion detection was featured on the Wolfram blog a while back :-) Perhaps that helps.

Comment: You might want to explore Optical Flow algorithms

Comment: Check Rudolph's Arduino based paint ball sentry http://www.geek.com/articles/geek-cetera/open-source-sentry-gun-means-guaranteed-paintball-victory-20120330/